# Public_activity - Destroy User's activities after Account cancelation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to achieve that when a user deletes his account, all his activities gets also deleted.

I'm on Rails 4 - Devise - Public Activity

My Registrations Controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_flashing_format?
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

end
```

To Destroy the comments record after a user deleted his comment i used:

```
@activity = PublicActivity::Activity.find_by_trackable_id(params[:id])
@activity.destroy
```

I'm searching for something similar, only to destroy all activities after account cancelation.

Anyone a good Solution ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in **User.rb** add a callback:

```
 before_destroy :delete_activities

 def delete_activities
    acts = PublicActivity::Activity.where(owner_id: self.id, owner_type: "User")
    acts.delete_all
  end
```

Comment: Yes.. That's the way I am also thinking to go ahead. Don't know any other better way, :)

Comment: Does it also delete associated object ? For example User has many articles, articles has many comments so do we need to write callback for each entity ? ( Assume those all models has PublicActivity included)

Comment: @Mansi if you have a relation in your model like `has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy` then on a user deletion his comments will be deleted as well, no need to write callbacks.

Comment: Does it also remove activities i.e. records of PublicActivity ?

Comment: @Mansi no, you'll have to do that like in my answer, not aware of any other solution at the moment. I don't see any downside of this.